# how do i check for a certain string in expect_out(buffer) and print expect_out(buffer) if it is found?

Tags: tcl, expect

I want to check if my `expect_out(buffer)` contains `%` as the first character on any line
if it is found then print the wole expect out contants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with expect. But if it's just a normal tcl string like:

```
%line1
^line2
&line3
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
set buffer "%line1\n^line2\n&line3"
foreach line [split $buffer "\n"] {
    if {[string index $line 0] == "%"} {
        puts $buffer; # prints the entire buffer, puts $line prints this line only
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,@ben i have another for loop in which i will execute this will this `break` statement will exit from this loop only or the outer loop and how can i delet trailing space before %

Comment: It will only break out of the inner loop. You can use `string trim` to remove the leading and trailing white-space. `string trimleft` will remove just the leading white-space. It's all here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M52

Answer (score 2):

[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm)'s -lineanchor option makes ^ match the beginning of lines instead of just the beginning of the string.

```
if {[regexp -lineanchor -- {^%} $buffer]} {
    puts -nonewline $buffer
}
```